# Is there a way to use exit animations with framer motion animate presence with router dom 6.8 (above 6.4)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, framer-motion

In earlier version with BrowserRouter, I could wrap the routes with animatePresence and that allowed for exit animations.

But now with createBrowserRouter it gives an error because animatePresence is not a router component. Is there any way to do that?

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="/" element={<RootLayout />}>
      <Route index element={<Main />} />
      <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
      <Route path="projects" element={<Projects />} />
      <Route path="contact" element={<Contact />} />
    </Route>
  )
);

function App() {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}
```

I tried to use it around the `<Outlet />` components and it bugged.
I tried to use it around the `<RouterProvider />` and also got an error.
I tried to only use animatePresence and useLocation on the motion div and did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still seeking for answer. I tried to wrap the Outlet component with motion component, and it worked.
Here is the code:

```
<AnimatePresence mode="wait">
  <motion.div
    key={location.pathname}
    initial={{ opacity: 0, x: 100 }}
    animate={{ opacity: 1, x: 0 }}
    exit={{ opacity: 0, x: 100 }}
    transition={{ duration: 1, ease: "easeOut" }}
  >
    <Outlet />
  </motion.div>
</AnimatePresence>
```